# wxFrame catch non-client area/border events?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a simple goal - I need to handle mouse events related to the border of a wxFrame (so-called "non-client area" events according to Windows). An example of an event is when the user clicks on the border of the frame. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you will need to implement it yourself with MSW only condition. I dn't think GTK/OSX support this. Also - what is your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

As this is fundamentally not portable, you need to use MSW-specific code for this. You can override `MSWHandleMessage()` in your `wxFrame`-derived class and handle `WM_NC*BUTTON*` messages there in whichever way you need.