# How to prevent user dragging window/frame

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to create a simple app that cannot be resized, minimised, maximised and moved. I've been able to fulfill all this requirements but one thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198657/8237838) but I cant find how to prevent window dragging.

I've tried to adapt [this C++ answer](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=7068) : when move event is trigerred, I just move back the window to its original position, but it's not very clean : it makes the windows shaky and sometimes minimize all other running apps. Also, the "Move" options is style available from system menu and I'd like to disable it.

So how can I disable dragging the window when clicking on title bar and disable Move option from system menu ?

I'm running `Windows 10`, `Python 3.10` and `wxpython 4.1.1`.

```
def __init__(self):
    # stuffs ...
    self.Center()
    self.Show()
    x, y = self.GetPosition()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.on_move)

def on_move(self, ev):
    ev.Skip()
    self.Move(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: Not sure but you might need to veto mouse event on the title bar. Also maybe this can give some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073708/wxframe-catch-non-client-area-border-events

Comment: @May.D, are you trying to emulate -kiosk-like behavior?

Comment: @Igor Sort of, but the app must not be fullscreen and I'd rather keep a title bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would never recommend having a window that is not moveable but if that is a game changer, in your specific situation, then you could define a window that has no frame and thus is not moveable.
The downside is that you would have to include any caption and a close facilty within the window yourself.
I'd also recommend making it `Always_on_top`.
As you can see, you gain the restrictions but lose compatability with other windows on the desktop.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, ("Moveable or Stuck"), size=(420, 210), \
                          style = wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR \
                          & ~(wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        caption = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Moveable or Stuck", pos=(10,5))
        caption.SetBackgroundColour('lightgrey')
        self.CloseButton = wx.BitmapButton(panel, bitmap=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_CLOSE), \
                                           pos=(380,5), size=(32,32))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR )
                
    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy() 

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but this is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I don't run windows OS so I can't test the `wx.EVT_MOVE_END` event, which should give you a better result.
The `style` gives you just a Close box and prevents the window being included in the taskbar.
Overriding the `Move` ability provided by the OS, is I believe, not possible, at an App level at least.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, ("Moveable or Stuck"), size=(420, 210), \
                          style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR \
                          & ~(wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        self.Pos = self.GetPosition()
        # other than Windows OS
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove)
        # Windows Only
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE_END, self.OnMove)
                
    def OnMove(self, event):
        self.SetPosition(self.Pos) 
        
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Indeed `EVT_MOVE_END` result is cleaner (no flickering) but does not remove ability to move the window (just move it back to original position when moves end). Using `EVT_MOVE` produces same result than `EVT_MOVE_START`.

Comment: @May.D, what if you create an empty `EVT_MOVE`?

Comment: @Igor can you elaborate ? I'm not familiar with wxpython.

Comment: @May.D, I think you can just use `pass`.